# Why won't the AMD Catalyst Control Center open?

Tags: ati, catalyst

When I try to launch it I get an error which mentions two reasons that might have caused this problem. Either there's no AMD graphics driver installed (I did install it, just not the post-release updates because they never do install.), or the driver's just not functioning properly. I only installed Ubuntu 12.04 not long ago so I'm not completely familiar with this OS yet. What do I do?

Comment: Can you add what Catalyst *exactly* says to your question. or launch it from the terminal, amdcccmle

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling drivers using terminal https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Comment: I just did. After I restarted it switched to old graphics mode. I had to uninstall again. Now I don't have the CCC anymore.

Comment: Now you have to install the drivers again https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI look in the section Manually installing Catalyst 12.6 . In case you want to use newer version, just enter into Google somthing like "ati driver -version- ubuntu 12.04 installing".